# Heroku - wkhtmltopdf - laravel-snappy : wrong path on production server

Tags: laravel, heroku, wkhtmltopdf

Here is my situation, I installed laravel-snappy which is a wrapper around wkhtmltopdf on my Ubuntu for a php project based on laravel framework.
I am in need to to convert html's to pdf and send them by email, so I am actually using a wrapper around wkhtmltopdf called laravel-snappy.

But the first issue I had to resolve, is that snappy was looking at the wrong directory on my ubuntu system so I made it work by creating a symlink to where it was looking for:
`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltodpf`
Now it just works fine on my local server.

But then when I deploy my application on heroku (cedar-14 stack), It does not work and here is the error message I receive (the same actually I had on my laptop):

`Apr 13 18:24:37 luckey app/web.1: stderr: "sh: 1: **/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: not found**`

Then I tried naively to do :
`heroku run "sudo ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf" --app luckey-dev

Running sudo ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf on luckey-dev... starting, run.4999 
Running sudo ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf on luckey-dev... connecting, run.499
Running sudo ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf on luckey-dev... up, run.4999
bash: **sudo: command not found**`

And then : 
`heroku run "ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf" --app luckey-dev

Running ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf on luckey-dev... up, run.5658
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf': **Read-only file system**`

I was wondering if adding this in the Procfile could work:
`system: sudo ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`
Seems that it will be started as a worker process type when you put your own name.

The thing is that I know that it was installed correctly trough a multi buildpack configuration because I can see the version on the server:

`heroku run "wkhtmltopdf -V" --app luckey-dev 
Running wkhtmltopdf -V on luckey-dev... up, run.3446
wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1 (with patched qt)`

So any idea how I can bring heroku to use the right binaries location, or to tell Snappy to execute wkhtmltopdf without looking for the binaries path because the alias wkhtmltopdf seems correctly created if I can get it's version with just typing executing wkhtmltopdf -V.

Any suggestion / idea will be appreciated :)

Comment: I saw a snappy.php file in the vendor  directory where I can see:

```'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    )``` maybe this could work if I let only wkhtmltopdf for the binary value, but how to do the change in the heroku server?

Comment: When i remove the symlink on /usr/local/bin/ and use the wkhtmltopdf command I have this: ```wkhtmltopdf 
-bash: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: No such file or directory
```
So this is essentially a wkhtmltopdf issue and not snappy I guess?

Comment: Maybe the issue comes from the buildpack I installed:
https://github.com/dscout/wkhtmltopdf-buildpack.git

Maybe I installed the wrong one (i386 vs amd63), I ll try to figure out the one I installed to try the other one. To be continued...

Comment: Ok I found the location of the binaries on the heroku with this command:
```heroku run "type -a wkhtmltopdf " --app luckey-dev                                                   
Running type -a wkhtmltopdf  on luckey-dev... up, run.5547
wkhtmltopdf is /app/.apt/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf```

I ll delete those comments after, and include them in the first topic when I ll get this shit done (I hope ^^)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to this issue:

First we had to fork the laravel-snappy of wraper of barryvdh in order to edit the snappy.php file for our own use:

`<?php
return array(
    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
    'image' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary'  => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env'     => array(),
    ),
);`

With heroku I could not create symlinks so I stopped looking for a way that.

**Solution 1: 'Meh'**
Then I tried to make the binary value of the pdf object match with the binary location of wkhtmltopdf on heroku. I could do it with this command:

`heroku run "type -a wkhtmltopdf " --app luckey-dev Running type -a wkhtmltopdf on luckey-dev... up, run.5547
 wkhtmltopdf is /app/bin/wkhtmltopdf`

Then editing the binary value on snappy.php file:

`'binary'  => '/app/bin/wkhtmltopdf'`

**Solution 2:'way better'**:solution 1 could be the solution(and it works), to give binary value this location. But there is even a better solution:

`'binary'  => 'wkhtmltopdf'`

Yup, straightforward, just give the alias... Heroku will know where to get it... Just make sure your wkhtmltopdf buildpacks in Heroku is well installed thanks to this command:
`heroku run "wkhtmltopdf -V" --app appName`

Then just for the record I had other issues because the html file I was trying to convert to pdf had some css files coming from another domain. You then get this error `Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError`.
To fix this you need to add a base tag on the html file, then all your relative url to the assets will be base on this base tag href:
`<base href="https://yourProductionDomain/">`

I'm glad I could make it this work.
Hope this might help someone else too.

Metux.

Comment: I was wrong about forking the project, you do not have to, you can just publish the config file and edit the binary path. My bad, not used to laravel yet :)